# For every element in a list a, how to count how many times it appear in one specific column in another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, apply, sapply

For every element in a dict a, I need to count how many times the element in 'age' column appears in one specific column of another dataframe in pandas
For example , I have a dict below:

```
a={'age':[22,38,26],'no':[1,2,3]}
```

and I have another dataframe with a few columns

```
TableB= {'name': ['Braund', 'Cummings', 'Heikkinen', 'Allen'],
 'age': [22,38,26,35,41,22,38],
 'fare': [7.25, 71.83, 0 , 8.05,7,6.05,6], 
 'survived?': [False, True, True, False, True, False, True]}
```

I would like to know how many times every element in dict a appears in the column 'age' in TableB. The result I expect is  `c={'age':[22,38,26],'count':[2,2,1]}`

I have tried apply function but it does not work. It comes with syntax error, I'm new to Pandas, could anyone please help with that? Thank you!

```
 def myfunction(y):
    seriesObj = TableB.apply(lambda x: True if y in list(x) else False, axis=1)
    numOfRows = len(seriesObj[seriesObj == True].index)
    return numofRows
 c['age']=a['age']
 c['count']=a['age'].apply(myfunction)
```

I would like to know how many times every element in list a appears in the column 'age' in TableB. The result should be
 `c={'age':[22,38,26],'count':[2,2,1]}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use merging of data frames to filter out the values that don't appear in `a` and just count the values.

```
import pandas as pd
a={'age':[22,38,26],'no':[1,2,3]} 

TableB= {'name': ['Braund', 'Cummings', 'Heikkinen', 'Allen', 'Jones', 'Davis', 'Smith'],
 'age': [22,38,26,35,41,22,38],
 'fare': [7.25, 71.83, 0 , 8.05,7,6.05,6], 
 'survived?': [False, True, True, False, True, False, True]}

df_a = pd.DataFrame(a)
df_tb = pd.DataFrame(TableB)
(pd.merge(df_tb, df_a, on='age')['age']
   .value_counts()
   .rename('count')
   .rename_axis('age')
   .reset_index()
   .to_dict(orient='list'))
{'age': [22, 38, 26], 'count': [2, 2, 1]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `value_counts` method with `pd.Series` and `to_dict` with `pd.DataFrame`

```
(pd.Series(TableB['age'])
   .value_counts()
   .loc[a['age']]
   .rename('count')
   .rename_axis('age')
   .reset_index()
   .to_dict(orient='list'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas.Series.value_counts() on the age column and select the results you're interested in. The following solution will also take into account possible missing values in your 'a' list.

```
a=[22,38,26,99]
TableB= {'name': ['Braund', 'Cummings', 'Heikkinen', 'Allen', 'John', 'Jane', 'Doe'],
 'age': [22,38,26,35,41,22,38],
 'fare': [7.25, 71.83, 0 , 8.05,7,6.05,6], 
 'survived?': [False, True, True, False, True, False, True]}

tableB_df = pd.DataFrame(TableB)
counts_series = tableB_df['age'].value_counts()
counts_series_intersection = counts_series.loc[counts_series.index.intersection(a)]
counts_df = pd.DataFrame({'age': counts_series.index, 'count': counts_series.values})
```

Have a look at the following resources for more info:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-with-list-with-missing-labels-is-deprecated

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html